# How to make an Image Hyperlinked using Aspose.Words DOM approach?

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to create a Word document using **Aspose.Words for .NET** using the **DOM** approach. How would I make an image hyperlinked?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Shape.Href property to set the URL.

```
Aspose.Words.Drawing.Shape shape = createOrFindShape();
if (shape.HasImage)
{
    // Set hyperlink using Shape.Href
    shape.HRef = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thank you. I was initially wondering how to do this using the FieldHyperlink class.